# How to handle optimistic locking in case of updated_all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, race-condition, optimistic-locking

I am trying to implement the Optimistic Locking for Race Condition. For that, I added an extra column `lock_version` in the Product: Model through migration.

Product: Model's new field:

```
#  lock_version                       :integer(4)      default(0), not null
```

When I try to `save!` Optimistic Locking is working. Records, updated_at and `lock_version` are getting an update.

However, in the existing source code, we are using `updated_all`, which does not update the `updated_at` and `lock_version`. So optimistic locking is not working. Please suggest, how to implement optimistic for `updated_all`

```
Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
      self.attributes = attributes
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you try the current approach? If so, can you post the error logs?

Comment: I don't think that you want to use update_all for this.  update_all bypasses all callbacks and is normally used when you want to do a bulk insert.   In this case you are looking up a single resource  by id so `find` would be better with standard `update`

Comment: @Austio You mean to say should I use                                                                       `prod= Product.find(:id => self.id) prod.update(attributes)`

Comment: Correct, you also don't need the hash rocket or specifying id `Product.find(self.id).update(attributes)`  There are other things you will have to consider like handling when it is not found.

Comment: @Austio Thanks for reply, then this will support Optimistic Locking

Answer (score 0):

We can simply do as.(in case callback is not needed.)

```
Product.where(:id => self.id, lock_version: params[:lock_version]).update_all('price = 0, lock_version = lock_version + 1')
```

That will looking for record with match lock_version and updating  lock_version.